# Nvda screen-reader reads "PageTitle document blank" when navigating one route to another in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

The issue observed is that when transitioning from one page to another, the speech reader reads the title of the previous page followed by a 'document blank' string while the next page is loading. This issue persists despite utilizing the titleService to assign specific page titles within individual components in Angular.

In app.component.html

```
<div id="main-content-wrap" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</div>
```

and from app.module.ts

```
router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.onNavigation(event);
 });


public onNavigation(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.preloaderService.show();
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.setBodyFocus(event);
      this.preloaderService.hide();
    }
  }


private setBodyFocus(event: NavigationEnd) {
    const bodyElement = $('#main-content-wrap')[0];
    bodyElement.focus();
}
```

but on screen reader it displayed like this "PageTitle Document Blank"
[Image Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU5op.png)

Expected : screen reader not read the previous page title document blank string.

Comment: It would be great if you could offer an interactive code example for us to reproduce. But for now, let me ask this: Where is focus going? Afaik best practice is to keep the focus on the triggering menu item, until the page has loaded, and then put it on the new content’s `<h1>` element. Focus must not get lost, especially while the page is loading.